# IntelliJ Expo Console Log Showing ANSI Escape Characters in Red Color

Tags: react-native, intellij-idea, expo

Running Expo SDK 42 to build a react-native front end on a window machine. This issue does not happen on my Mac. When expo tries to build the app it displays information in red. All the red text displays what looks like ANSI escape characters. How do I fix this?[image: Console Sample]